# How to make border from Windows application in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, border

I'm programming in NetBeans, Java Swing.

**1.** I want to set border for **undecorated frame** like this in Windows 10 - this slight blue shadow:
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0Frj.png)

If u don't see this little shadow, I mean something like that:
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkdLW.png)

I can do BevelBorder like that:

```
getRootPane().setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK));
```

That is giving normal black, bevel border, but when I'm doing similar thing with ShadowBorder it doesn't work or the whole frame is white. It doesn't work by making `frame.setBorder(border);` either.
What should I do to set this ShadowBorder and manipulate it(I mean manipulate color, size and etc.)?

Comment: You should ask two separate questions and not combine them. Neither question is fully clear to me.

Comment: Ok, so I leave only one topic. Can somebody help about that?

Comment: Still -- can you clarify your question??

Comment: Do you mean the translucent border ***outside*** the window? That is supplied by Windows. If the user wanted it, it will be supplied by Windows. If they switched that off, one app. should not try to re-enable it (especially not on OS X or *nix). Agree with @HovercraftFullOfEels though, it is still not entirely clear what you mean.

Comment: I want to add shadow for my undecorated frame(like this programs in Windows have), how can I do that?

Comment: Ok, i did that. I used DropShadowBorder from SwingX to make shadow of my mainpanel. It worked!